# how to download ajax control tool kit source?

Tags: asp.net, ajax, jquery, asp.net-ajax, ajaxcontroltoolkit

I have searched hours for the source version of the ajaxcontroltoolkit but could not find it. I get only the binaries version. I am studying the library so want to peek into the source code. please give me the link if somebody knows where. I am using Visual Studio 2008.

Answer (score 2):

Did you check the source control on [codeplex site](http://ajaxcontroltoolkit.codeplex.com/SourceControl/list/changesets)?

> There is download option on right side

Hope it helps

Comment: Here is the latest:  http://ajaxcontroltoolkit.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/1014bf767f65  You can poke around in there with your browser.  There is also a Download link on that page.  The source is all there.